# Is there a way to use/call COM interfaces in C?

Tags: c, windows, com

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694363(v=vs.85).aspx) has reference that C language can also be used to create and use COM objects.

I went through CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C) and found that relevant header files are created and they will be included in whichever C application that calls these COM interfaces.

Will all COM objects from Windows will have similar relevant header files?

Or is there any other way to call COM interfaces from C ?

Comment: If built properly, likely by the interface definition language compiler (MIDL), then yes, there will be corresponding C interface definitions. You're already on the right track. And fyi, COM from C is a f'ing *pain*, but it is doable none-the-less.

Comment: COM is **designed** to be callable from C. If respective header files are missing, you will have to reconstruct the lpVtbl manually. Entries are sorted in the same order they are declared, with base interfaces going first.

Comment: It is possible, the practice is however outlawed by the Geneva Convention on Programmer's Rights.  We subscribe to that here, you will rarely get useful help when you run into trouble.  You will run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Will all COM objects from Windows will have similar relevant header files?*

All header files generated from a [Microsoft Interface Definition Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367091.aspx) file using the [MIDL compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693359.aspx) will contain definitions for use by C programs. See [C/C++-Compiler Considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366771.aspx):

> The generated .h file has both C-style and C++-style definitions for interfaces.

I don't know if **all** COM objects that ship with Windows or the Windows SDK come with pre-built headers for use by C programs, but it certainly would be reasonable to assume so. In case you find an interface for which there is no C-style interface definition, you can always run the MIDL compiler against the .idl file.

> *Or is there any other way to call COM interfaces from C ?*

Some COM interface implementations also come as [type libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366844.aspx) (.tlb). You can [#import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) the TLB into your C++ code. This generates a primary header file (.tlh) you could use to reconstruct a C-style interface definition.